# Postfix not accepting recipient address: connect to private/policy: Connection refused

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis, clamav

I thought I'd be clever and add amavis/spamassassin/clamav to my working Postfix installation. I got it working and then made a change. Walked away, had a beer, then found out I'd mucked up. This is what's happening now

```
Oct  2 22:01:59 wilma postfix/smtpd[1048101]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-pf1-f172.google.com[209.85.210.172]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256
Oct  2 22:01:59 wilma postfix/smtpd[1048101]: warning: connect to private/policy: Connection refused
Oct  2 22:01:59 wilma postfix/smtpd[1048101]: warning: problem talking to server private/policy: Connection refused
Oct  2 22:02:00 wilma postfix/smtpd[1048101]: warning: connect to private/policy: Connection refused
Oct  2 22:02:00 wilma postfix/smtpd[1048101]: warning: problem talking to server private/policy: Connection refused
Oct  2 22:02:00 wilma postfix/smtpd[1048101]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-pf1-f172.google.com[209.85.210.172]: 451 4.3.5 <---@---.kiwi.nz>: Recipient address rejected: Server configuration problem; from=<---@gmail.com> to=<mike@----.kiwi.nz> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-pf1-f172.google.com>
Oct  2 22:02:02 wilma postfix/smtpd[1048101]: disconnect from mail-pf1-f172.google.com[209.85.210.172] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 bdat=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

I've searched Google high and low looking for an answer, it seems that "451 4.3.5" is a generic error thing.

Here is master.cf ...

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup     fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp -o smtp_fallback_relay=
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
smtp-amavis unix -       -       n       -       2       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/amavis -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200 -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes -o disable_dns_lookups=yes -o max_use=20 -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n   -       n       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/10025 -o content_filter= -o mynetworks_style=host -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 -o local_recipient_maps= -o relay_recipient_maps= -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes -o smtp_tls_security_level=none -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none -o smtpd_restriction_classes= -o smtpd_delay_reject=no -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions= -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0 -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001 -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000 -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0 -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0 -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings
```

main.cf is

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
command_directory = /usr/sbin
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 1
debug_peer_list =
default_privs = mail
delay_warning_time = 4
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/regexp_table
html_directory = no
in_flow_delay = 1s
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
local_transport = local
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/virtual
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 3221225472
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 25971520
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, lists.$mydomain
mydomain = mike-mac.gen.nz
myhostname = mail.mike-mac.gen.nz
mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.3.0/24 webmail.mike-mac.gen.nz localhost.localdomain localhost
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.0.13/README_FILES
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
reject_code = 550
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.0.13/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 4
smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access
smtpd_proxy_options = speed_adjust
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_sender_domain, check_policy_service unix:private/policy, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 2
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/Email_cert/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/Email_cert/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
strict_mailbox_ownership = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
undisclosed_recipients_header = To: NotSayingWhoGetsThis:;
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaildomains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 2147483648
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox,hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-user-map-family.kiwi.nz,hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-user-map-coders.kiwi.nz,hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-user-map-mak.co.nz,hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-user-map-lessonplans.kiwi.nz
virtual_minimum_uid = 1
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:8`
```

The running daemons are

```
systemctl status postfix postgrey amavis spamassassin clamav-freshclam
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2021-10-02 21:58:34 NZDT; 29min ago
    Process: 1047688 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1047688 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma systemd[1]: Finished Postfix Mail Transport Agent.

● postgrey.service - LSB: Start/stop the postgrey daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/postgrey; generated)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-10-02 21:58:34 NZDT; 29min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 1047510 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/postgrey start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 17839)
     Memory: 18.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/postgrey.service
             └─1039871 postgrey --pidfile=/var/run/postgrey.pid --daemonize --inet=10023

Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma postgrey[1047518]: whitelisted: 194.7.234.142/32
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma postgrey[1047518]: whitelisted: 194.7.234.143/32
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma postgrey[1047518]: whitelisted: 213.143.66.210/32
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma postgrey[1047518]: Pid_file "/var/run/postgrey.pid" already exists.  Overwriting!
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma postgrey[1047583]: Process Backgrounded
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/stop the postgrey daemon.
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma postgrey[1047510]:    ...done.
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma postgrey[1047583]: 2021/10/02-21:58:34 postgrey (type Net::Server::Multiplex) starting! pid(1047583)
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma postgrey[1047583]: Resolved [localhost]:10023 to [127.0.0.1]:10023, IPv4
Oct 02 21:58:34 wilma postgrey[1047583]: Binding to TCP port 10023 on host 127.0.0.1 with IPv4

● amavis.service - LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/amavis; generated)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-10-02 21:58:35 NZDT; 29min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 1047562 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/amavis start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 17839)
     Memory: 160.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/amavis.service
             ├─1047705 /usr/sbin/amavisd-new (master)
             ├─1047714 /usr/sbin/amavisd-new (virgin child)
             └─1047715 /usr/sbin/amavisd-new (virgin child)

Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma amavis[1047705]: No ext program for   .zoo, tried: zoo
Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma amavis[1047705]: No ext program for   .doc, tried: ripole
Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma amavis[1047705]: No decoder for       .F
Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma amavis[1047705]: No decoder for       .doc
Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma amavis[1047705]: No decoder for       .lrz
Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma amavis[1047705]: No decoder for       .zoo
Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma amavis[1047562]: Starting amavisd: amavisd-new.
Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma amavis[1047705]: Using primary internal av scanner code for ClamAV-clamd
Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter.
Oct 02 21:58:35 wilma amavis[1047705]: Found secondary av scanner ClamAV-clamscan at /usr/bin/clamscan

● spamassassin.service - Perl-based spam filter using text analysis
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/spamassassin.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-10-02 21:58:36 NZDT; 29min ago
    Process: 1047534 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1047641 (spamd)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 17839)
     Memory: 109.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/spamassassin.service
             ├─1047641 /usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid --create-prefs --max-children 5 --username >
             ├─1047711 spamd child
             └─1047712 spamd child

Oct 02 21:58:33 wilma systemd[1]: Starting Perl-based spam filter using text analysis...
Oct 02 21:58:36 wilma systemd[1]: Started Perl-based spam filter using text analysis.

● clamav-freshclam.service - ClamAV virus database updater
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-10-02 16:08:46 NZDT; 6h ago
       Docs: man:freshclam(1)
             man:freshclam.conf(5)
             https://www.clamav.net/documents
   Main PID: 990816 (freshclam)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 17839)
     Memory: 227.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/clamav-freshclam.service
             └─990816 /usr/bin/freshclam -d --foreground=true

Oct 02 21:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 21:09:46 2021 -> main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, >
Oct 02 21:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 21:09:46 2021 -> bytecode.cld database is up-to-date (version: 333, sigs: 92, >
Oct 02 22:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 22:09:46 2021 -> Received signal: wake up
Oct 02 22:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 22:09:46 2021 -> ClamAV update process started at Sat Oct  2 22:09:46 2021
Oct 02 22:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 22:09:46 2021 -> ^Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
Oct 02 22:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 22:09:46 2021 -> ^Local version: 0.103.2 Recommended version: 0.103.3
Oct 02 22:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 22:09:46 2021 -> DON'T PANIC! Read https://www.clamav.net/documents/upgrading->
Oct 02 22:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 22:09:46 2021 -> daily.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 26309, sigs: 19380>
Oct 02 22:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 22:09:46 2021 -> main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, >
Oct 02 22:09:46 wilma freshclam[990816]: Sat Oct  2 22:09:46 2021 -> bytecode.cld database is up-to-date (version: 333, sigs: 92,
```

I realise my biggest mistake was one of stupidity, I should have taken backups of the main and master.cf files before starting. Having said that, can anyone see what I can't ?

```
postconf -n
access_map_reject_code = 550
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
command_directory = /usr/sbin
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 1
debug_peer_list =
default_privs = mail
delay_warning_time = 4
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/regexp_table
html_directory = no
in_flow_delay = 1s
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
local_transport = local
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/virtual
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 3221225472
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 25971520
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, lists.$mydomain
mydomain = mike-mac.gen.nz
myhostname = mail.mike-mac.gen.nz
mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.3.0/24 webmail.mike-mac.gen.nz localhost.localdomain localhost
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.0.13/README_FILES
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
reject_code = 550
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.0.13/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 4
smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access
smtpd_proxy_options = speed_adjust
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_sender_domain, check_policy_service unix:private/policy, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 2
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/Email_cert/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/Email_cert/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
strict_mailbox_ownership = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
undisclosed_recipients_header = To: NotSayingWhoGetsThis:;
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaildomains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 2147483648
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox,hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-user-map-family.kiwi.nz,hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-user-map-coders.kiwi.nz,hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-user-map-mak.co.nz,hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-user-map-lessonplans.kiwi.nz
virtual_minimum_uid = 1
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:8
```

```
postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup     fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp -o smtp_fallback_relay=
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
smtp-amavis unix -       -       n       -       2       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/amavis -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200 -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes -o disable_dns_lookups=yes -o max_use=20 -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n   -       n       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/10025 -o content_filter= -o mynetworks_style=host -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 -o local_recipient_maps= -o relay_recipient_maps= -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes -o smtp_tls_security_level=none -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none -o smtpd_restriction_classes= -o smtpd_delay_reject=no -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions= -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0 -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001 -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000 -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0 -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0 -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings
```

Comment: Both your quoted files appear incomplete. Please use `postconf -n` and `postconf -M` to dump a *complete* copy of your (non-default) configuration.

Comment: I have edited the question to include output from both postconf queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Postfix cannot process mail because your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` configuration instructs to `check_policy_service`, but the referenced policy service cannot be queried** (likely, because it is no longer started).

> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = ..., check_policy_service
> unix:private/policy, ...

That setting specifies a UNIX socket path relative to the *chroot* (i.e. `/var/spool/postfix/private`), but neither does the name say what this is, nor does your `master.cf` contain a line that would make postfix start such policy service to listen on that socket.

Since your `postconf -M` dump does not mention it.. you may have unintentionally deleted a line in your `master.cf` that was supposed start it. If it was started by other means, it would not likely be placed into the `private` directory.

Did you setup any additional mail filters, like rate limiting, SPF or temporary deferrals (*"greylisting"*)? If my guess is correct and this *was* previously configured in your `master.cf`, all you have to do is

- delete the references to the policy services from the restriction lists, if you are not using it, **OR:**
- re-add the lines in master.cf that define which program is actually called when the policy service `unix:private/policy` is queried.

You may find useful information on what *was* previously listening on that UNIX socket by investigating file ownership, or searching for logs mentioning `private/policy` but predating your recent changes.

Comment: I'd set up greylisting and SPF but thought I'd removed them from main.cf with a view to adding them back later.

Comment: It was hidden in smtpd_recipient_restrictions as check_policy_service unix:private/policy. Thank you for your help